Specify that a group of users should be members of a MongooseIM MCU
When creating a multi-user-chat (MUC) room in MongooseIM, I would like to indicate that a whole organization should be members of that room.  So, I could create a Sales-Chat room for all members of Sales org.
I have seen a way of doing this in OpenFire - but can't find it in MongooseIM.  Is there a name for this type of MUC membership in MongooseIM?
I have seen that vCard.organization can be used to group a block of users, but this can't be used in MCU-Add.  Obvs - my client app could loop through all users to find those in a particular org, and add them individually - but that wouldn't capture new users being added to the organization.
